# Enabling Pop-ups by default for all layers in Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: popup, arcgis-portal

I would like for Pop-ups to be enabled by default for all layers within portal.

For example, if a user goes to the "Map" tab whithin portal and adds a map service layer, I want "Enable Pop-up" to be set by default. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So not a full answer, but you could look at this option for working directly with the json configuration file. You may be able to script something to set the pop-up option to be enabled for all layers:

[Automating Pop up configuration of web app in ArcGIS for Portal?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167150/automating-pop-up-configuration-of-web-app-in-arcgis-for-portal)